# How to install Xeus-cling without Anaconda?

Tags: c++, jupyter, cling

Why is Anaconda package manager necessary to install `Xeus-cling`? 
I have only used pip so far, and switching to a new package manager seems like a lot of work. I want to start using C++ with Jupyter, but all the installation instructions assume `conda` package manager.

Does anyone know of Xeus-cling installation which doesn't require Anaconda?

Answer (score 4):

Pip is a package manager for python. It is mostly meant for packaging pure Python packages even though shipping some binary extensions is possible.

`xeus-cling` is a native application, which relies on a number of other libraries, including LLVM, Clang, Cling, Xeus, OpenSSL, libzmq and other. Vendoring the entire LLVM stack in a pip package would be unreasonable.

The developers of `xeus-cling` have made the choice of `conda` because it is a general-purpose cross-platform package manager, but it could be packaged for other general-purpose package managers, such as Debian's `dpkg`, OSX's `Homebrew`, `conan.io` or others.

Comment: I think that it's just a bad excuse in first place, why can not they just make a static build and ship it as a pip package. For example a great success story for this is the "opencv-contrib-python" package, which allows you to start prototyping in python within seconds in different opencv versions.